# Axios can't get object by ID react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a component Active.js, that lists items thought axios get, and then there is a link on name (sub-component ActiveDetails.js) that I wish returns that specific object user clicks on in order to get more details. But it returns an empty object. ID is undefined. [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p14ve.png)
How link id of object to specific url?

```
import axios from 'axios';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Active extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            activeVisitors: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8085/api/visitors/')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ activeVisitors: res.data._embedded.visitorList, });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h1>Active visitors</h1>
                <div >
                    <ol>
                        {this.state.activeVisitors.map(activeVisitor =>
                            <li key={activeVisitor.id}>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                       <Link to={`/active/${activeVisitor.id}`}>Name: {activeVisitor.name}</Link>
                                 </div> <br/>
                                 <button onClick={this.handleRemoveClick}>Remove</button>
                                        Time: {moment(activeVisitor.dateTime).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}<br />
     
                                </div></li>)}
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class VisitorDetails extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
            this.state = {
                 visitors: {},
        };
    }
     componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8085/api/visitors/${this.state.id}`)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ visitors: res.data._embedded.visitorList });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <div className='item'>
                        {this.state.visitors.id}
                        Name: {this.state.visitors.name}
                        Badge Nr: {this.state.visitors.accessCardID}
            </div>  
</>

    )
        }
    }
```

Comment: You didn't show where you're using `VisitorDetails` but anyway you're not assigning `id` in state anywhere so yes it will be undefined. Maybe you're confusing state with props?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add that from App.js <Route path='/active/:id' component={VisitorDetails}/>.
Isn't that assigning this.state.id? cause I want  to get this.id axios.get(`http://localhost:8085/api/visitors/${this.state.id}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `VisitorDetails.js` extract the `id` from props as shown below. When you pass an id using `react-router-dom` that `id` will be added inside `params` of the `match` property from where you can access the `id` value.

In your case as the path associated with the component is `'/active/:id'`, you can access the value using `id` prop as shown below

```
.........
.........
.........

componentDidMount() {
 const { id } = this.props.match.params
 axios.get(`http://localhost:8085/api/visitors/${id}`)
      .then(res => {
          this.setState({ visitors: res.data._embedded.visitorList });
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
      });

}
.........
.........
.........
```

Comment: Note that you can simply do `.catch(console.log)`